# how to print an array in smarty?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I have an array:

```
 $team_details = Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => doge_finder [total_rewards] => 52.00524500 [desciption] => team is only of doge miners [created_by] => 20 );

/* assigning to a smarty template */
$smarty->assign("team_record", $team_details);          
$smarty->display($tpl);
```

In template file:

```
{foreach from= $team_record key=team item=trecord}
{$trecord[$key].name}
{/foreach}
```

In result output must be "doge_finder", but I got first initial character of each record in array ie. "1 d 5 t 2"

how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: isnt this `    {$team_record.name}` enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use `{foreach}` if you just want to print one associative array. Just use `$array.key` format.

In this case, you should print the name by using:

```
{$team_record.name}
```

If you have multiple associative arrays. You can use:

```
{foreach from=$team_record key=team item=record}
    {$record.name}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: thank you, it's working fine. Because of I have an associative array that's why I wrote {foreach} to print that array.

Comment: if there multidimensional array like: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => doge_finder [total_rewards] => 52.00524500 [desciption] => team is only of doge miners [created_by] => 20 [created_date] => ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Late Miner [total_rewards] => 45.25462000 [desciption] => Team player are late coin miners [created_by] => 20 [created_date] => ) ) 

then may I know how can it possible to print only name field in this array?

Answer (score 10):

we can Use `{$team_record|print_r}` to dsiplay **whole** Array in the smarty file.

**Output:**

```
 Array
 (
    [id] => 1                  
    [name] => doge_finder
    [total_rewards] => 52.00524500
    [desciption] => team is only of doge miners
    [created_by] => 20
)
```

we can Use below Code to **iterate** the Array in Smarty file

```
{foreach from=$team_record key=arrayIndex item=trecord}
   {$arrayIndex}: {$trecord}
   <br>
{/foreach}
```

**Output :**

```
       id: 1

       name: doge_finder

       total_rewards: 52.00524500

       desciption: team is only of doge miners

       created_by: 20
```